# C# Index and length must refer to location within string

Tags: c#, .net

On running below program error is shown
**

> Unhandled Exception : systemArgumentOutofRange:Index and length must
>   refere to location within string.

**

```
string input = "OneTwoThree sdfhguiosdrb asdhfuiaserthf aseiryaseuigraweui";           

int size = input.Length;
if (input.Length > 30)
{
    msg1 = input.Substring(0, 30);
    msg2 = input.Substring(msg1.Length, size);
    Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", msg1);
    Console.WriteLine("\nMessage: {0}", msg2);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Please help what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are doing wrong on this line

```
msg2 = input.Substring(msg1.Length, size);
```

what you are doing here is, creating a substring `msg2` that is longer then the size of your first string `msg1`,

here, your `msg1.Length` equals `30` and your `size` equals `58` means that  you are trying to create a string having `startingIndex = 30` and `Length = 58` and this will be impossible in this condition, because the Length of your second string `msg1` is `30` and it is less then `Size i.e. 58`.

Albin Sunnanbo answer is good as per your requirement.i.e.

```
msg2 = input.Substring(msg1.Length, size - msg1.Length);
```

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
msg2 = input.Substring(msg1.Length, size);
```

to

```
msg2 = input.Substring(msg1.Length, size - msg1.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
msg2 = input.Substring(msg1.Length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your single line of msg2 = input.Substring(msg1.Length, size);

with the

```
msg2 = input.Substring(0, size);
msg2 = msg2.Remove(0, msg1.Length);
```

And problem willbe resolved.

```
string input = "OneTwoThree sdfhguiosdrb asdhfuiaserthf aseiryaseuigraweui";
        int size = input.Length;
        if (input.Length > 30)
        {
            string msg1;
            string msg2;
            msg1 = input.Substring(0, 30);
            **msg2 = input.Substring(0, size);**
            **msg2 = msg2.Remove(0, msg1.Length);**
            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", msg1);
            Console.WriteLine("\nMessage: {0}", msg2);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine(input);
```